# Google Storage: remove customer supplied encryption key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with files. Each file has customer supplied key that needed while you want to access this file.

My question if it's possible to remove the custom key and became the encryption key managed by Google (default option)?

If it's possible, how to remove a customer supplied key from existing file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`gsutil rewrite`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rewrite) command to do this, by first removing the key from your [`boto config`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil) file, and then running:

```
gsutil rewrite -k gs://your-bucket/your-object
```

If you want to do it without removing the key from your boto config file you can make a temporary file without that key present and run:

```
BOTO_CONFIG=temp_file gsutil rewrite -k gs://your-bucket/your-object
```